# Kettle Datedif month issue

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I need to reproduce the kettle Datedif function in the R programming language. I need the 'datedif month' option. I thought reproducing would be pretty easy but I have some 'weird behaviour' in pentaho. As an example:

ID       date_1      date_2 monthly_difference_kettle   daydiff_mysql

15943   31/12/2013  28/07/2014        7                      209

15943   31/12/2011  27/07/2012        6                      209

So in pentaho kettle I used the formula-step and the function DATEDIF(date2,date1,"m"). As you can see when I calculate the daily difference in mysql I get for both records the same amount of days in difference (209), however, when the monthly difference is calculated via the formula step in pentaho kettle I get a different result in months (7 and 6 respectively). I don't understand how this is calculated...

Can anyone produce the source code for the 'DATEDIF months' function in pentaho? I would like to reproduce it in R so I get exactly the same results.

Thanks in advance,
best regards,

Comment: Why are there different dates in your sample lines? The second line includes a 29-day February because 2012 is a leap year while 2014 is not. It's likely a bug in leap year handling on one side or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about mysql, but i think it is the same. In PostgreSQL date difference gives integer value (in days). It means both rows has total match in days.

Calculating month difference non trivial. What is month (28, 30, 31 day)? Shall we count if month is not full?

Documentation states **If there is not a complete month between the dates, 0 will be returned**

But according to source code easy to understand how calculated datedif:

Source code available via github https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/blob/f7defbcfc0e8f48ad2b139fe9820445f052e0e78/libraries/libformula/src/main/java/org/pentaho/reporting/libraries/formula/function/datetime/DateDifFunction.java

```
private int addFieldLoop( final GregorianCalendar c, final GregorianCalendar target, final int field ) {
c.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );

target.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
target.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
target.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
target.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );

if ( c.getTimeInMillis() == target.getTimeInMillis() ) {
  return 0;
}

int count = 0;
while ( true ) {
  c.add( field, 1 );
  if ( c.getTimeInMillis() > target.getTimeInMillis() ) {
    return count;
  }
  count += 1;
 }
}
```

Append 1 month to start date till it will become bigger then end date

Comment: It is worth to mention the way GregorianCalendar.add() method works with respect to months. Once you add 1 month to 31/12/2013, you'll get 31/01/2014. Then you'll get 28/02/2014 and then 28/03/2012, and so on. This way, on the 7th iteration you'll arrive exactly to 28/07/2014, and you will need one more iteration to exceed the target date. While starting from 31/12/2011 after same 7 iterations you'll arrive to 29/07/2014, thus exceeding the target date. The value returned by addFieldLoop is iteration number - 1.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, this helps a lot. So when 'passing' february it actually does something weird that instead of going till the end of the next months, it only goes to the number of days in february?

Would this be the same situation in following case:
say I need to go from 31/03/2015 to 30/09/2016:
start: 31/03/2015
+ 1 month
30/04/2015
+ 1 month
30/05/2015 --> instead of normally 31/05/2015
+ 1 month
30/06/2015
+ 1 month
30/07/2015 --> instead of normally 31/07/2015

So rule would be take the lowest 'day-number' to go further in the loop?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it seems so. This is the line printed by this loop, after putting print right after c.add() for going from 31/03/205 to 30/09/2016 (I've incremented month by 1, so that it won't start from 0): 2015/4/30 -> 2015/5/30 -> 2015/6/30 -> 2015/7/30 -> 2015/8/30 -> 2015/9/30 -> 2015/10/30 -> 2015/11/30 -> 2015/12/30 -> 2016/1/30 -> 2016/2/29 -> 2016/3/29 -> 2016/4/29 -> 2016/5/29 -> 2016/6/29 -> 2016/7/29 -> 2016/8/29 -> 2016/9/29 -> 2016/10/29

Comment: THANKS MAN, that really helped me a lot. Is it me or is this rather strange behaviour? I've had to write several lines of code in R to duplicate this function...

If you want you can create an answer and I'll market it as 'answer'. This was what I needed...

thank you!